# OAuth redirect URI alternatives for non-web applications?

Tags: redirect, oauth, oauth-2.0, response, google-oauth

What would be the best way to handle redirect URIs for OAuth authentication?

In a few projects, I used to boot up a web server that would wait for the authentication to be sent back. Is there any way to trigger any type of code without a local web server, or is it the recommended way?

I'm not asking for help about any specific languages, this is more like a language agnostic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Side note: nice avatar... :)</sub>

Deciding on the best approach will depend on the exact scenario and any additional requirements your application might have, however, we can look at a few options and possible implication of choosing them.

The [OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-9) suggests a few options to solve this issue, either using an embedded user-agent or relying on an external one.

The embedded user-agent may allow you better control on the UI aspects, however, by leveraging an external user-agent your users might benefit from an already established session and avoid having to input credentials one more time.

For an external user-agent we have a few options:

> External user-agent - the native application can capture the response from the authorization server using a **(1)** redirection URI with a scheme registered with the operating system to invoke the client as the handler, **(2)** manual copy-and-paste of the credentials, **(3)** running a local web server, **(4)** installing a user-agent extension, or by **(5)** providing a redirection URI identifying a server-hosted resource under the client's control, which in turn makes the response available to the native application.

**Option 1:**

You configure a redirect using a custom scheme that your application registered in the operationg system, this way your application gets called when an external user-agent receives a response indicating a redirect to your scheme.

**Option 2:**

You redirect somewhere that just shows a pretty page with the code and ask the user to input it manually in your application.

**Option 3:**

You already used this one, basically the application starts a local web server and you configure the redirect to be something along the lines of `http://localhost:[port]/`.

**Option 4:**

By installing a user-agent extension you would have code running with the browser that could communicate the code automatically to your applications.

**Option 5:**

You configure a redirection URI that points to some server-side code you host and that your client Android application is aware of so that it can grab the code from that URL.

---

For much more information on this topic, check: [OAuth 2.0 for Native Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-04)

As an additional not, if you don't want to go full server-side on the options that require some logic on the server, you can accomplish the same using much less lines of code by writing your server-side logic as a [Webtask](https://webtask.io/) (be sure to use a custom domain).

**Disclosure**: I'm an Auth0 engineer.

Comment: Thank you. I was just wondering if my approach was "acceptable", got a nice understanding.

Comment: there's also WIP on https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-device-flow-03 if you want to apply a flow without a web server and a redirect URI