# React Native Deep Linking Android

Tags: android, oauth, instagram, deep-linking, react-native

I am making an App that allows user to login with Instagram. Now the login procedure that I've understood is as follows:

1. Register the App at Instagram Developer as a client to acquire client_id etc.
2. Call the Instagram URL along with your client_id with get the grant_code
3. Send the grant_code back to Instagram (I'm going to do this from back-end) to get the access token.

[This StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40754034/react-native-instagram-explicit-authentication) has the same problem I do. I understand from the answer that I need deep linking so that I can provide it as a redirect_uri to Instagram so that It redirects back to my app after login.

Now I can't get the Deep Linking to work. Below is the component where the app is listening for the URL.

### Top Most Component in The App

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
      if (url) {
        console.log(`Initial url is ${url}`);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
  }

  handleOpenURL(event) {
    console.log(event.url);
  }

  render() {
    return <Router />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

### Android Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.numu"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.numu.com/app” -->
            <data android:scheme="http"
                  android:host="www.numu.com"
                  android:pathPrefix="/app" />
            <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "numu://app” -->
            <data android:scheme="numu"
                  android:host="app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

### This is my Router Component

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import IntroText from './components/IntroText';

const RouterComponent = StackNavigator({
  LoginPage: { screen: LoginPage, path: 'login' },
  IntroText: { screen: IntroText, path: 'intro },
});

export default RouterComponent;
```

This is my progress so far. I have been testing by entering http://www.numu.com/app/intro and numu://app/intro into my chrome browser (mobile), but the app doesn'r open.

I would also appreciate if anyone could tell me an alternative to this method. I have tried a package for this purpose. It also requires that I give a redirect_uri

Thanks

Comment: You must use a proper redirection mechanism like `<a href=...>` or `window.location = ...`. It won't work if you simply copy/paste the url into your browser (expected behavior btw).

Comment: I don't understand. I want the user to press a button which will take him to the instagram login page (WebView inside my App). When the login is successful Instagram will redirect back to my app, because I will have specified the http://www.numu.com/app/login or numu://app/login as the redirect_uri.

Where do I use the anchor tag or window.location = ... 

P.S: I don't <a> are included in JSX

Comment: Use this method to test if your app correctly respond to the url

Comment: I logged into StackOverFlow from my mobile and opened the url from here. It redirects back to my app :') So I expect that this should redirect back to my app if I add it as redirect_uri in the developer's portal as well. Right ?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: Hi, so it doesn't automatically redirect me to the right component, but it doesn't exit the app either. Also I got the grant code and the redirect uri from instagram so I guess manually set navigate to where ever I want now.